# Spark update column value from another column based if null or empty

Tags: apache-spark

I am newbie in Spark but very curious on Spark performance tuning. I have a large data frame that needs to update the column (say column `A`) with value of another column (say column `B`) from the same data frame, if current column value is null or empty. Here is my practice:

```
val cleanDF = originDF.withColumn("A", when(col("A").isNull || col("A") == "", col("B")))
```

Here are my questions:

1. Is there a better way of `null` check? In Java world there is Apache common library provide API to check a String `isBlank`. Is there anything similar available in Spark?
2. How is the performance impact of the or (`||`) condition if validate on huge dataframe
3. Is there a better option to run this column update task with better performance? I know `UPDATE` can be expensive in Spark so just wondering good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)You can use commons lib. Add --jars "path to your commons jar file" to your spark shell or submit

2)You are doing a one pass on Dataset (plus constant time to check and copy colB to colA), it should be O(N)

3)your colA (potentially, if blank) replaced by colB from the same Row, it is not expensive. I cannot confirm, but I am assuming all the data of a Row resides in the same node.

```
scala> val df = Seq(
     |   (null, "A"),
     |   ("", "B"),
     |   (" ", "C"),
     |   ("D", "DB"),
     |   ("E", null)
     | ).toDF("colA","colB")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [colA: string, colB: string]

scala> df.show
+----+----+
|colA|colB|
+----+----+
|null|   A|
|    |   B|
|    |   C|
|   D|  DB|
|   E|null|
+----+----+


scala> val myudf = udf{(x:String) => org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isBlank(x)}
myudf: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,BooleanType,Some(List(StringType)))

scala> df.select(when (myudf($"colA"), $"colB").otherwise($"colA") as "colA", $"colB").show(false)
+----+----+
|colA|colB|
+----+----+
|A   |A   |
|B   |B   |
|C   |C   |
|D   |DB  |
|E   |null|
+----+----+
```

Comment: thank you for the prompt solution. Could you please suggest the solution not change the column from select but instead make in to the dataframe? Because i still try to write the data hack to Hive.

Comment: any transformations creates a new dataframe. They are immutable.